# Strange behaviour Django shell and iPython

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, ipython, django-shell

I was doing some stuff in the Django console and I realized that the global variables are not recognized inside the `lambda` expression, for example if you execute the following code inside a python or even inside an iPython console it works perfectly:

```
a = 10
foo = lambda x: x + a
foo(10) # returns 20
```

But if you execute it inside the Django shell with iPython it doesn't work:

```
In [8]: foo = lambda x: x + a

In [9]: a = 10

In [10]: foo(10)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <module>()
----> 1 foo(10)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 foo = lambda x: x + a

NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
```

The iPython version 0.13.2

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

Event if I assign `a` before the lambda funciton the problem stills:

```
In [1]: a = 10

In [2]: foo = lambda x: x + a                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [3]: foo(10)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <module>()
----> 1 foo(10)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 foo = lambda x: x + a

NameError: global name 'a' is not defined

In [4]: 
───────────
```

Comment: if you access `a` what happens?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It does not happend anything, the problme stays inside the lambda expression

Comment: try assigning `a = 10` before the lambda function.

Comment: What version of django are you using? How are you starting the ipython shell, with `python manage.py shell -i ipython`? Your code works for me using the ipython shell on django 1.8.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be experiencing the bug others have encountered here:

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/62#issuecomment-3854940

As explained in the thread a little further down, prior to version 1.6, django was starting the ipython shell using the `IPython.embed()` function, which was forcing ipython to start with separate local and global namespaces.

The django team fixed this issue in 1.6 in this commit: https://github.com/django/django/commit/3570ff734e93f493e023b912c9a97101f605f7f5

Here is a backport fix for older versions of Django (1.4.14 in this case): https://github.com/theatlantic/django/commit/9dfe12c40af23956dc12e3427e3e7e63ebc360c9

You can reproduce this issue if you manually call `IPython.embed()` inside of another function (creating a closure), even if you use a regular python/ipython shell. Tested with ipython 3.1.0:

```
>>> from IPython import embed
>>> def test():
...     embed()
... 
>>> test()
Python 2.7.9 (default, Feb 10 2015, 03:28:08) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 3.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: a = 10

In [2]: foo = lambda x: x+a

In [3]: foo(10)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-08cbc4a9df91> in <module>()
----> 1 foo(10)

<ipython-input-2-3ecd5afea150> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 foo = lambda x: x+a

NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
```